# GeneratedPluginRegistrant don't can not be applied - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, background-service

When I build my Flutter app, this error shows:

error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

I went to the github of class and saw the difference: https://github.com/theyakka/fluro/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

If I put this in my project, when I build application, my class change automatically for this:

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
  }
}
```

I follow this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuAzXY_KOo

I need to run my app in background to get the current location, but don't works.

Comment: I got the same issue. How do you get around it?

Answer (score 0):

You need import the plugin,

`import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;`

and extend your class with FlutterActivity.